# How to synchronize branches with "merge" command in SVN?

Tags: java, svn

I have a same file in two branches;

SVNTest.java in /svn/branch/SVNTest-2.1

```
public class SVNClass{
    private String b;
    private String c;
}
```

SVNTest.java in /svn/branch/SVNTest-2.2

```
public class SVNClass{
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

When I merge with;

```
svn merge /svn/branch/SVNTest-2.1/SVNTest.java@HEAD /svn/branch/SVNTest-2.2/SVNTest.java@HEAD workspace/SVNTest.java
```

I am getting property a and b only, but I am trying to sync up two branches that I would like to have all three properties like a, b and c in my working copy. How can I synchronize two branches without losing data if let's assume there is no conflict at all?

Answer (score 0):

1. There **is** conflict here, which can't be resolved automatically
2. 2-URL Merge is bad and wrong choice, re-read `svn help merge` for "2-URL Merge Example"